# Convergence of Integrals of Exponential Functions

Tags: integration

Let $f$ be a non-negative real valued function on $[a,b]$, and let $p:[a,b]\to(1,\infty)$ such that $f^p\in L^1([a,b])$. Let $p_n:[a,b]\to(1,\infty)$ be a (uniformly bounded) sequence of (step-)functions converging to $p$ wrt. the $L^1$-norm, i.e. $||p_n-p||_{L^1([a,b])}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

**Question:** Does
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^bf(x)^{p_n(x)}dx=\int_a^bf(x)^{p(x)}dx
\end{align*}
hold in general?

If $f$ is bounded, the proof is easy using the Lipschitz continuity of exponential functions. But what if $f$ is unbounded? I neither know if $f^{p_n}$ is in $L^1$, nor I could find a counterexample.
Any help, ideas, hints or even counter examples are highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is negative: On $[0,1]$ define $p\equiv 2, p_n(x) = 2 +\chi_{(1/n,1/(n-1))}, n= 2,3,\dots$ Then $p_n \to p$ in $L^1.$

Now define

$$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{2^n}\frac{\chi_{(1/n,1/(n-1))}}{\sqrt {x-1/n}|\ln (x-1/n)|}$$

and put $f=\sum f_n.$ Then $\int_0^1 f^2 < \infty.$  But for each $n$

$$\int_0^1 f^{p_n} \ge \int_{1/n}^{1/(n-1)}f_n^3 = \frac{1}{2^{3n}}\int_{1/n}^{1/(n-1)}\frac{1}{(x-1/n)^{3/2}|\ln (x-1/n)|^3 } \  dx = \infty.$$